# find elements values are flows through the code without properly sanitized or validated. This may enable an second order SQL injection attack

Tags: pymongo, sql-injection, checkmarx, secure-coding

```
tags = mycoll.find({"category": "movie"}).distinct("tags")
```

I have used above code in django and feel it's there is no issue with
But checkmarx throwing error

Help?

Comment: Is this the verbatim code, or is it something which were generated by some other code?  If the former, then you're correct, and the code can't be injection attacked.

Comment: I have copy pasted from my code base

Comment: And this issue reported by checkmarx tool